# Getting the content of a pandas row based on some conditions of other row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame df1 with the following content:

```
Serial N         year         current
   B              10            14
   B              10            16
   B              11            10
   B              11            
   B              11            15
   C              12            11
   C                            9
   C              12            13
   C              12           
   D               3             4
```

I would like to count the number of occurrences of of each serial unique serial. If the serial number is less than 2, I would like to replace year and current for that row to nan. I would like to have something like this:

```
Serial N         year         current
   B              10            14
   B              10            16
   B              11            10
   B              11            
   B              11            15
   C              12            11
   C                             9
   C              12            13
   C              12 
   D              nan           nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `value_counts`, `lt` and `reindex` to get a boolean array of where to change values to `nan`, and then use `loc` to make the changes.

```
serial_filter = df1['Serial N'].value_counts().lt(2).reindex(df1['Serial N'])
df1.loc[serial_filter.values, ['year', 'current']] = np.nan
```

The resulting output:

```
  Serial N  year  current
0        B  10.0     14.0
1        B  10.0     16.0
2        B  11.0     10.0
3        B  11.0      NaN
4        B  11.0     15.0
5        C  12.0     11.0
6        C   NaN      9.0
7        C  12.0     13.0
8        C  12.0      NaN
9        D   NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """Serial_N         year         current
   B              10            14
   B              10            16
   B              11            10
   B              11            nan
   B              11            15
   C              12            11
   C              nan              9
   C              12            13
   C              12           nan
   D               3             4"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True)
df1.columns = ['Serial N', 'year', 'current']
```

Now I have the same `df1` you showed above.

#### Solution

```
serial_filter = df1.groupby('Serial N').apply(lambda x: len(x))
serial_filter = serial_filter[serial_filter > 1]
mask = df1.apply(lambda x: x.ix['Serial N'] in serial_filter, axis=1)
df1 = df1[mask]
```

#### Demonstration and Explanation

```
serial_filter = df1.groupby('Serial N').apply(lambda x: len(x))

print serial_filter

Serial N
B    5
C    4
D    1
dtype: int64
```

produce a count of each unique `Serial N`

```
serial_filter = serial_filter[serial_filter > 1]

print serial_filter

Serial N
B    5
C    4
dtype: int64
```

Redefine it such that it only includes those `Serial N`'s greater than 1

```
mask = df1.apply(lambda x: x.ix['Serial N'] in serial_filter, axis=1)

print mask

0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Create a filter mask to use on `df1`

```
df1 = df1[mask]

print df1

  Serial N  year  current
0        B  10.0     14.0
1        B  10.0     16.0
2        B  11.0     10.0
3        B  11.0      NaN
4        B  11.0     15.0
5        C  12.0     11.0
6        C   NaN      9.0
7        C  12.0     13.0
8        C  12.0      NaN
```

Update `df1`

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I actually wanted to replace the row with a count less than 2 with nan. That was what I wanted. can I ajust your code to do that?